# Unable to edit MSI file, Orca, and other msi editors all opening as read only windows 7

Tags: windows, windows-installer

I am asking a question about how to change attributes of MSI file while it is being stored in temp folder during run time.

I need to install DELL wireless 5530 drivers on the Laptop DELL precision M6500

http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2011/05/27/installing-dell-wireless-5530-hspa-mini-pci/

I am following the above article, however Orca seems to opening in READ only mode and not allowing me to modify the attributes. In the blog comments few people have encountered the Orca read only but they haven't given the resolution to change the read mode to write mode.

[Orca opening read only image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8YlBU.png)

OS : WINDOWS 7 64 BIT
I have turned off the UAC in windows.

Any ideas, where I might be going wrong and what could be done.

Comment: Can you copy over the temp file to your desktop and then try editing?

Comment: I can copy the temp files of MSI, store it on the different folder, edit it. however it doesn't compile everything back together. the installer crashes.

Comment: This is the link to the driver, can you try editing and removing the rows (CustomAction | Authenticate:, InstallExecuteSequence | Authenticate, InstallUISequence | Authenticate:)                               http://speedy.sh/M4cp9/Dell-Driver-for-wireless-card-5530.zip

Comment: Try and let me know: http://speedy.sh/nQHby/Dell-5530-Wireless-Broadband-Package.zip

Comment: It worked Ganesh, thanks a lot